# No less a person than someone (meaning)

Tags: meaning

I have the following sentences:

1. This was made crystal clear by President Franklin Roosevelt, the principal author of the "Four Freedoms" and the Atlantic Charter.
2. This was made crystal clear by **no less a person than** President Franklin Roosevelt, the principal author of the "Four Freedoms" and the Atlantic Charter.

What's the meaning of the expression "**no less a person than**" ? 
What's the difference in meaning between sentence #1 and #2? 
When do you use the expression "**no less a person than**" ?

Comment: See this question, which covers similar ground: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212002/no-less-than-idiom-root/212010#212010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression used to emphasize the person cited:

***[no less a person than](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-less-a-person-than)*** (in American)

> a person of no lower importance, rank, etc. than

(Collins Dictionary)

Usage examples from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no%20less%20a%20person%20than%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20less%20a%20person%20than%3B%2Cc0):

> He was the hero of a remarkable episode, having succeeded ***no less a person than Vittorio Alfieri*** in the affections of ***no less a person than Louise de Stolberg, Countess of Albany***, widow of ***no less a person than Charles Edward Stuart***, the second pretender to the British crown. Surely no woman ever was associated ...From [A Little Tour in France](https://books.google.it/books?id=R_FcDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA91&dq=%22no%20less%20a%20person%20than%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq1qy984TgAhWCLewKHWKeCLkQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22no%20less%20a%20person%20than%22&f=false)
>   By Henry James

Comment: What If the person cited is not important or not very important and you just want to emphasize them. 

For example:
- _This is **no less a person than** my friend Timmy._ (Introducing Timmy to others)

Is it possible to use the expression in cases like this?

Comment: @JorgeElSoñador - yes, in that case you are saying that your friend Timmy is important to you.

Comment: Generally in the case of a non famous person like Timmy➖you might add➖no less a person than my best friend Timmy or another such descriptive.